# Sending JSON with SignalR

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json, signalr

I want to send objects from Javascript to Server using Signalr, but the server side method isn't invoked.

```
// Model-Class generated by EF5.0
public partial class ttFragen
{   
     ...
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> UserID { get; set; }
    public string Titel { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ProductID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Score { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
}

public class Chat : Hub
{

    public void Send2(ttFragen frage)
    {
       ...
    }

}
```

Client-Code:

```
 $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {

 $("#broadcast").click(function () {
 var frage = {
            ID: -1,
            UserID: -1,
            Titel: "titel2",
            Text:"testsst",
            ProductID: -1,
            Score: -1,
            Date : null
           };

chat.server.Send2(frage); // nothing happens
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

on Client the function has to start lowercase. So changing the call to:

```
chat.server.send2(frage);
```

fixes the problem

Comment: i lost half a day to this issue. seems bizarre to not only enforce casing style, but fail quietly when wrong case is used.

Comment: @SonicSoul -> You might want to use [HubMethodName("<yourmethodname>")] on your Hub method, with this you can customize method names as per your requirement